# Bug when popToViewController second time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using a popToViewController to remove all opened segues. I am doing the following:

```
let mainView = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! MainNavigationController

let secondView = mainView.viewControllers[0] as! SecondViewController

mainView.popToViewController(secondView, animated: false)
```

and when I do it the second time the whole view became white and everything disappears. Why it happens, when I call it the first time it is fine but on the second the bug is appearing. I am doing it to remove the segues.

Comment: Can you provide more info about what logic is implemented while calling this code snipper the second time?

Comment: it is the same code above, it is method and when I call it second time it becomes to buggy

Comment: @Trutinetko print the `mainView.viewControllers[0]` in the log and show here that log.

Comment: How do you call this logic? from which ViewController? this force casting is not good, try use guard statements to safely check the relevant VC's exist.

Comment: from the print <MyApp.SecondViewController: 0x1020ad500>

Comment: Can you check the list of available controllers in the navigation stack? i tried using your code and see no issues when called multiple times.